Confusion regarding addresses and references in C++. What are the data types of addresses and references respectively?
I understood that the & operator is context dependent,
int var = 5;
int* ptr = &var; 

In the above code, &var returns the address of var, then gives it to the pointer.
On the other hand
int &ref = var;

This second code is going to make an alias for var.
Now, this sentence confuses me (gathered from LLMs and also just reading stuff online):
"The address itself is a pointer value because it represents a specific location in memory where the variable a is stored."
I am confused regarding the address of var having a type apparently? Isn't the expression &var just supposed to return a hex code that indicates the location in memory? How does the address itself have a datatype apparently (in this case, int*)? Is this something the compiler figures out? And like, how is the address itself a pointer, what is the meaning of "the address itself is a pointer value"?
Also, if I may ask another complementary q related to this, what is the data type of references then? How are references connected to pointers? As this also confuses me:
"References in C++ are not just addresses; they also include type information about the data they refer to, ensuring type-safe operations."
I know it's a long question, but I've been busting my head on this stuff, I need this explained

&var has type int* which is called a pointer type.

int* ptr is different from int foo.  You can't store &var in foo because it is not a int*

"How does the address itself have a datatype apparently? Is this something the compiler figures out? ..." The question seems to indicate that you're not using a good c+ book. I would recommend one of the best beginner book called c++ primer by lippman as this question is just too broad and unfocussed. A book will explain this in much more detail than any SO answer.

An int is a number. And the pointer is also a number, A type defines the operations that can be done on the value. For example you can divide an int, but you cannot divide a pointer, although they are both numbers, also you can dereference a pointer. But not an int.

@3CxEZiVlQ &var is simply a pointer to var. It's not quite right to say that's a "numeric value", per se.  pointers are not ints, thought they can convert to ints sometimes.

See what are compound types in c++. C++ is one of the most difficult/complicated language. It takes years to learn it properly. Even then experienced programmer make plenty of basic mistakes in C++. Only a good book or the standard itself will help one learn c++ properly.

@3CxEZiVlQ: Not even that.  On a 64bit system, a pointer to a member function is usually 128 bits long.

"I understood that the & operator is context dependent," -- It might be better to call & a token, since it does not function as an operator in int&. And, if it doesn't confuse you more, keep in mind that the expression 2 & 3 is yet another meaning (bitwise-and) for this token.

"the address of var having a type apparently?" -- C++ is a strongly typed language. Everything has a type. (Even functions have types.) Plus, there is no contradiction to the expression &var having a type and it evaluating to "a hex code that indicates the location in memory". Reconciling those two views is as simple as viewing the type int* as "a hex code that indicates the location in memory", similar to how the type int can be viewed as "a number". (Neither view is precise, but they have the general idea.)

var is of type int, and has the value 5.  The expression &var computes the address of var, which has the type int *.  Since int *ptr = &var declares ptr as a pointer to an int (i.e. an int *) and &var produces a result of type int * (the types are compatible) ptr is initialised with a value equal to &var i.e. ptr is a pointer of type int *, and its value is the address of var.    In int &ref = var, the & is NOT an operator - it is syntax for declaring ref as a reference to (also called, in some contexts, an "alias of" or "alternative name of") var.
